# Tengo error de sintaxis sin tener error de sintaxis en Laravel

Tags: laravel, sintaxis

Me sale:

> syntax error, unexpected '('

En la línea 45 pero tengo todo bien. Adjunto código

```
$file = $request->file('image-profile');
if($file){
        //Get unique name from image
        $image_path = time().$file->getClientOriginalName();

        //Save the image on disk
        \Storage::('user')->put($image_path, \File::get($file));
        
        $user->image = $image_path;
    }
```

La línea 45 es la siguiente:

```
\Storage::('user')->put($image_path, \File::get($file));
```

Comment: Debería ser `Storage::disk()` ... Por ejemplo `Storage::disk('local')`

Comment: Aqui [puedes revisar la sintaxis](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-local-driver) correcta

Answer (score 3):

Como te lo mencionaron en los comentarios, la manera correcta es `Storage::disk('some-disk')->put('...');`.

Puedes leer la documentación de Laravel sobre ese tema, te dejo el enlace aquí [aquí](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#obtaining-disk-instances).

Lo que se le pasa como parámetro del método `disk()` es alguno de los discos que tienes hayas definido en tu archivo `filesystems.php`. Te muestro su contenido:

```
<?php

return [

  'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),
  
  'disks' => [
        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'tmp' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root'   => storage_path('tmp'),
        ],
        
        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL'),
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
        ],
        
        'public_folder' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path('images'),
            'url' => '/images',
        ]
    ]
];
```

En tu archivo `env` puedes tener una variable llamada `FILESYSTEM_DRIVER` con el valor de algunos de los discos que existen en tu arreglo `disks` del archivo `filesystems.php`. De esta manera, lo correcto es que definas un disco en esa variable del archivo `env` y de esa manera evites usar el método `disk()` cuando uses la clase `Storage`.

De esa manera siempre usarás el mismo disco por defecto cuando uses la clase `Storage`.

Ahora, si por alguna razón necesitas cambiar de disco en alguna parte de tu código, lo implementarías de la siguiente forma:

```
Storage::disk('local')->... // El resto de tu lógica
```

Comment: Me sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Pero qué es lo que muestra el error?

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '('

Comment: En cuál línea? Necesitas darnos más detalles acerca de lo que sucede, con ese tipo de información no podemos hacer mucho

Comment: Ya mencioné la linea.

Comment: Actualiza tu pregunta con las líneas que preceden y siguen a la línea con el error

Comment: Ahí actualicé la pregunta

Comment: Yo veo que aún tienes el error de Storage::('disk')

Comment: Ahí también lo actualicé... y continúa el error...

Comment: @alfonsosarmie si ese es tu código actual entonces aqui tienes un error: **`$file = $request->file('image-profile')`** ¿qué paso con el `;` del final de la sentencia?

Comment: Lo agregué en el código original. Pero de todos modos sigue arrojando el error...

Answer (score 0):

Pregunta solucionada!
Los pasos que seguí fueron los siguientes:

1. Borrar el caché y datos de navegación
2. Revisar la documentación oficial
3. Copiar y pegar la documentación oficial (con respecto a los 'disk' y metodos de Storage)

Comment: Copiaste y pegaste toda la documentación?, O de esa doc. Que usaste?

Comment: Copié y pegué todo lo referido a los disk y a los metodos de Storage.

Comment: Deberías aclarar eso en tu respuesta para que a otros con un problema similar les sea fácil entender la solución

Comment: Ahí aclaré. Soy nuevo en esto xD